# fail2ban hanging on creating SSL Certificates all day

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, fail2ban

I tried installing fail2ban today on my ubuntu 16.04 server. It seemed to install correctly. Unfortunately, this command has been running now for over 3 hours.

```
Creating/Updating SSL(for TLS) information
Creating /etc/mail/tls/starttls.m4...
Creating SSL certificates for sendmail.
```

This is my first AWS EC2 Ubuntu box, so all this technology is extremely new to me. I'm not quite sure how to handle this situation.
This is the information it has posted to the console just prior to this `hanging`.

```
    Setting up sendmail-bin (8.15.2-3) ...
    Updating sendmail environment ...
    Reading configuration from /etc/mail/sendmail.conf.
    Validating configuration.
    Writing configuration to /etc/mail/sendmail.conf.
    Writing /etc/cron.d/sendmail.
    Disabling HOST statistics file(/var/lib/sendmail/host_status).
    Reading configuration from /etc/mail/sendmail.conf.
    Validating configuration.
    Writing configuration to /etc/mail/sendmail.conf.
    Writing /etc/cron.d/sendmail.
    Could not open /etc/mail/databases(No such file or directory), creating it.
    Reading configuration from /etc/mail/sendmail.conf.
    Validating configuration.
    Creating /etc/mail/databases...

    Checking filesystem, this may take some time - it will not hang!
      ...   Done.

    Checking for installed MDAs...
    sasl2-bin not installed, not configuring sendmail support.

    To enable sendmail SASL2 support at a later date, invoke "/usr/share/sendmail/update_auth"
```

I'm not quite sure what to do here, whether it be stop fail2ban cancel the process? Like I said, this is my first ubuntu box so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: That didn't look like anything to do with `fail2ban`.  It's more reminiscent of an incomplete previous install.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like an entropy problem at a first glance. Virtual machines sometimes lack entropy, please do this to check:

```
cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail
```

If it's very low, you can try:

```
apt-get install rng-tools
rngd -r /dev/urandom
```

And then check again, and try generating the ssl certificate again.

If this is not the case, please install strace and run the command you tried; have a look what's hanging.

Comment: Adding to @Craig's answer, in VMs I'd use [HAVEGEd](http://www.issihosts.com/haveged/) over rngd.

Comment: Yeah, a hanging RNG operation is waiting for entropy. On a console you can sometimes get enough by e.g. repeatedly pressing the shift key.